# Curl chunked uploads with PHP

Tags: php, http, iis, curl, libcurl

I have written a PHP script that is using CURL to transfer large files from one Windows server to another. Both are running IIS, which has a 2GB limit for file uploads. My process works great for files less than 2GB. However, it fails for files > 2GB.

I have heard that CURL may have the ability to send files in chunks, which may solve my problem. However, I can't find any good examples of how to do this. My current working code is posted below. Does anyone know how to modify it to send my files in chunks (i.e. 100MB chunks)?

```
$postVars = array("file1" => $fileContents1,
                  "file2" => $fileContents2,
                  "outputPath" => $outputPath);

// Initializing curl
$ch = curl_init();

// Configuring curl options
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, $username . ":" . $password);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, false);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FRESH_CONNECT, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BUFFERSIZE, '64000');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, '3');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Content-type: multipart/form-data'));
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 5.01; Windows NT 5.0)");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS,$postVars);

echo "Sending files...\n";
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 9999);

if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
{
    echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
}
else
{
    echo 'Operation completed without any errors';
}

$info = curl_getinfo($ch);
print_r($info);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: AFAIK PHP cannot properly handle a file upload larger than 2GB. I spent a great deal of time writing a python upload handler to get around this.

Comment: So this can't be done? There has to be some way that PHP can handle > 2GB uploads.

Comment: I don't remember the specifics, but PHP has something bunged up in its core even in the 64-bit versions, and [I don't think it has been solved yet](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=27792) unless you want to compile a custom PHP binary.

Answer (score 0):

[plupload](http://www.plupload.com/) is a javascript/php library, and it's quite easy to use and allows chunking of your desired size.

It uses HTML5 though. `I found only the way to uploading a large file is PlUpload Library` and make the FileManager Application. Hope it will help you also.